# Angular : This type is not supported as injection token

Tags: angular, typescript

I'am trying to create a constructor with type `string` but I'am getting the error as:

> This type is not supported as injection token

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class DataService {
     constructor(url:string, private http:HttpClient) { 
     }
}

export class PostService extends DataService {
    constructor(http:HttpClient) {
         super("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",http);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the error that you encounter is this one:
Compiled with problems:X

```
ERROR

src/app/services/data.service.ts:14:23 - error NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter 'url' of class 'DataService'.
  Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.

14   constructor(private url: string, private http: HttpClient) {}
                         ~~~

  src/app/services/data.service.ts:14:28
    14   constructor(private url: string, private http: HttpClient) {}
                                  ~~~~~~
    This type is not supported as injection token.
```

The DataService class (extended by PostService) should not be injectable. Injectable means that the class (so DataService) is available to be provided and injected as a dependency, which should not as its purpose is to provide a shape or a reusable service (to avoid writing same code in several services)

the solution is to comment out the Injectable decorator in DataService

```
// @Injectable({
//   providedIn: 'root',
// })

export class DataService {
  constructor(private url: string, private http: HttpClient) {}
```

And PostService should look like:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PostService extends DataService {
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', http);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that by declaring `DataService` as `@Injectable`, all constructor parameters need to be injectable and there's no `string` value injectable. Plus, in the opposite way, the `PostService` would not receive an `httpClient` injected instance if not declared as `@Injectable`.

You probably don't want to be able to inject `DataService` anywhere, right? It is aimed at being an abstract class, right?

If so, you should declare the concrete class(es) as `@Injectable`:

```js
export abstract class DataService {
     constructor(url:string, private http:HttpClient) { 
     }
}

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class PostService extends DataService {
     constructor(http:HttpClient) {
         super("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",http);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will to my knowledge not work, as the constructor is just used for dependency injection.

Generally, I found subclassing components in Angular always rather fiddly and brittle, so I would try to avoid it completely. Instead: Delegate/compose instead of inherit. ([edit] I just saw that this is not about a component, apologies)

Anyways, if you want to stick to extending, in your specific case the following might work instead:

```js
export abstract class AbstractDataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  /** Provided by subclasses. */
  protected abstract getUrl(): string;
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PostService extends AbstractDataService {
  protected getUrl(): string {
    return 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  }
}
```

Instead of setting the property via constructor, supply it through an abstract method which you implement in your subclasses.